# jquery Button that submits form when it is supposed to do nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-button

I got a problem with a jQuery button, it is inside an HTML `<form>` and basically if a certain condition is verified it has to submit the form, else it has to do nothing but it submit the form anyway... the code is:

```
$( "#feasibility_button_top" ).button().click(function(){
if(checkMandatoryFieldFeasibility().value)){
    setMethod(0, null, 'insertFeasibility');
    return false;
}
```

but if i add an else condition like this:

```
else{
     return true;
}
});
```

the button instead of submit the form (when it is supposed to do nothing), it reload the page.
I have this problem in Fire Fox but not in IE6....

Thx
Daniele

Comment: Is the button a normal button or is it a submit button?  <input type="button" /> or <input type="submit" />

Answer (score 1):

There's an extra ) in there `if(checkMandatoryFieldFeasibility().value))`
Also what does checkMandatoryFieldFeasibility().value return if you alert it? Is it true or false?

Answer (score 0):

Try having this condition instead:

```
if(checkMandatoryFieldFeasibility().value.length == 0) {
    setMethod(0, null, 'insertFeasibility');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using e.preventDefault();

e being the event passed in.
I.E:

```
.click(function(e) {
....
e.preventDefault
...
});
```